# symfony2 FOSUserBundle generate alphanumeric username

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, alphanumeric

in my Symfony project I have different types of users:
2 admin accounts with ids 1 and 2 and username can be anything
100 account for the company with the ids of 3-102 and username must be AA001 to AA100
and accounts for ordinary users with username AA101, AA102, ...

the two admin accounts and the accounts of the company I will create a symfony command to generate them.

my question is how to generate the user name for others who will use the registration form so that the first who will register his username is AA101 and so on

my first idea :
recover id max (maxid) and use ($username = 'AA'.maxid-1)
but what happens if two users register at the same time

second idea :
persist the entity and get its ID (afterpersist events) and use ($username = 'AA'.id-2)
This method avoids the risk of having the same user name for both accounts
but what to put in the username before persist

I don't know where to start and which method is the best.
so any advice or any idea will be very helpful

PS:sorry for my english

Comment: actually second idea looks better than first, at the default you can set username to some default value and then it will be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution for now

the user class

```
<?php
namespace FM\FmBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class Users extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        parent::setEmail($email);
        parent::setUsername($email);
    }
}
```

the post persist event listener

```
<?php
namespace FM\FmBundle\EventListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;

class UserPostPersistListener
{
    private $needsFlush;
    public  function __construct(){
        $this->needsFlush=false;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $user = $args->getEntity();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        if($user instanceof Users) {
            $number=$user->getId()-2;
            $user->setUsername('AA'.$number);
        }

        $em->persist($user);
        $this->needsFlush = true;
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if ($this->needsFlush) {
            $this->needsFlush = false;
            $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

app/config/service.yml

```
fmarketUserPostPersistListner:
        class: FM\FmBundle\EventListener\UserPostPersistListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

app/config/security.yml

```
providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

but no thing happen the username is still the same as the user email,
when i replace

```
if($user instanceof Users) {
            $number=$user->getId()-2;
            $user->setUsername('AA'.$number);
        }
```

by

```
$number=$user->getId()-2;
$user->setUsername('AA'.$number);
```

it work fine

I tried this before the if

```
dump(get_class($user));
dump($user instanceof Users); die;
```

it give

```
UserPostPersistListener.php on line 17:
"FM\FmBundle\Entity\Users"
UserPostPersistListener.php on line 18:
false
```

my question is why the class name of $user is Users but its not a instance of Users?
and without the if statement the code will be executed for every entity

Comment: the php function is_a($user,'Users') give false
is_a($user,'FM\FmBundle\Entity\Users') give true, so I can use the if statement